# Azure Active Directory User report

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a user report out of Azure AD. I need The report needs to have the username, last login and creation date. The GUI only goes back 30 days

I've tried get-mguser -all but it doesnt have all the properties like I would see if I were using get-aduser. Same thing holds true for get-azureaduser -all $true. Any help out there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `beta` version of Graph API because information about last signed-in date is available only in `beta`. The properties you need are `userPrincipalName`, `createdDateTime` and `signInActivity`.

```
# switch to using beta version
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users
Get-MgUser -Property "userPrincipalName,createdDateTime,signInActivity" 
#second option
Get-MgUser | Select "userPrincipalName,createdDateTime,signInActivity"
```

Documentation:

[User properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties)

[signInActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signinactivity?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: Thanks for trying but this doesnt work. Only returns ID and DisplayName.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this in Graph explorer with beta version,i am able to fetch the results

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/User-Id?$select=signInActivity
```

[image]

Comment: I can but I havent figured out how to export it into something readable for management.