# Microsoft Graph

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having an issue with getting all the information to display correctly. I want The username, Last login, and created date. What I have below gives me the top 50 displaynames or if I remove "| select 'DisplayName'" it gives me the top 50 user logins. How do I display both. I'm sure its something stupid that I'm missing.

```
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'AuditLog.Read.All'
$user = Get-MgUser -Top 50  -Property 'SignInActivity' | select 'DisplayName'
$user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
```

Comment: remove the `-Top 50` to get more then 50 elements, 2nd remove the `Select Displayname` if you want to see the `SignInActivity` information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Active Directory User report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751273/azure-active-directory-user-report)

Comment: @Avshalom Nope. Its the same issue. The suggested solution doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the properties to be returned in `-Property` parameter. Properties separated by a comma.

```
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'AuditLog.Read.All'
$users = Get-MgUser -Property 'DisplayName,SignInActivity'
# another option
$users = Get-MgUser | Select DisplayName,SignInActivity
```

Comment: Thank you for trying but this doesnt work.  It only returns ID and Display Name. Microsoft Graph seems to be very different from what I'm used to

Comment: @user770022 You can also try another option with Select instead of Property: $users = Get-MgUser | Select DisplayName,SignInActivity

Comment: @user770022 You seem to be guessing. I've been working on this all weekend and come to understand the get-mguser is much different than a get-aduser command.

Comment: I've read doc for Get-MgUser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0 and how to use -Property. If you try to run the query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,SignInActivity in Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) it will generate a code snippet for PS. Where did you find the information that you need AuditLog.Read.All scope? Check the documentation about permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: If you check note in doc about signInActivity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties Details for this property require an Azure AD Premium P1/P2 license and the AuditLog.Read.All permission